# Best suited methods to include large number of images,videos,pdf in an offline application

Tags: android, image, pdf, video

I need to develop an offline application in which it has got around 700 images, around 100 videos, 100 pdf's need to be included along with apk.Currently i have put images in drawable folder,videos in raw folder, and pdf in asset folder.When i build the application including all this apk size goes upto 1.5gb.My question is
1.Is it appropriate to include images and video in res folder?Is there any other method to handle this situation 
3.One peculiar error will get generated when you build the app that is "package r does not exist android studio".Even though apk gets generated,studio shows this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best suited for this is to use "facebook conceal"

Answer (score 0):

It's best to make use of [Google Play APK Expansion Library](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/google/play/expansion-files.html) for handling large application data. Imagine having the user download/install a single 1.5GB APK file.

Comment: Thank you for answering question,i have gone through apk expansion library but i need to secure images and video for this they have suggested joob tool but my problem is 1.the size of resource may go more than 4 gb .Since only max two expansion for an apk and i not releasing in the play store.So any suggestion to this?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason: R is re-generated by your environment everytime you add a new resource, as you are using a lot of files this may take time and during the process you will get the error R doesn't exist

Best way would be if you keep the app light without images and videos, only download the files from the server after the user installs the app, on a per need basis. You can save these in the SD card and save users on phone storage space as well.

Comment: Thankyou for replay, The app will work completely in offline mode.As you suggested if i store in sd card, how to secure images and videos?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if there's gonna be so much data then it should not be in stored in the App (APK). Also google doesn't allow this big APK to be uploaded at once, the big apps are divided into parts. You must have seen for the big games it first downloads a game, it starts and then downloads big amount of data later. But in your case I think the standard way to handle this situation would be to keep all this data on the server and whenever you need it just request it from there.